# ¿Cómo conectar Drupal 7 con MS SQL y IIS 7?

Tags: php, sql-server

Estoy montando una Web en Drupal conectado con `MSSql` y `IIS7` pero tengo problemas para la instalación de `Drupal`, más que todo por un error que me sale en el cuarto paso. Acá los datos:

- SO Windows 7 Ultimate
- MS SQL Server 2014 express (SQLEXPRADV_X64_ES).
- Drupal 7.41.
- PHP 5.5.12 (instalado con wampserver 2.5 x86)
- IIS 7.5
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
- php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
- php_wincache.dll

Me he guiado de este [tutorial](http://nicolasleroy.be/blog/connecting-drupal-ms-sql-server) pero el problema está en el WinCache. Además de usar el `PHP Manager` del `IIS`.

[image: Error en el cuarto paso]

Es aquí donde me he quedado. He buscado la solución e incluso baje una DLL.

- php_wincache.dll (wincache-1.3.5-5.5-nts-vc11-x86.exe)

Y al ver en mi `phpinfo();` me sale que están cargadas las librerías para SQL Server pero no la del WinCache.

otro mensaje que me salió al iniciar el wamp fue:

[image: warning al iniciar wamp]

De repente tengo que cambiar las versiones de algo o alguna configuración que me ha faltado ya que buscando en google he encontrado muy poco.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si quieres levantar un Drupal corriendo IIS con SQL Server,

debes tener lo siguiente:

- Microsoft WebMatrix como IDE -> levanta un IIS Express y con un addon
  tenemos soporte para PHP
- Drupal Core 7.21
- Drive Drupal para SQL
- SQL Server 2008 Express

.

1. Una vez que descargamos y descomprimimos el Core de Drupal en algún lado de nuestro disco duro, donde procederemos a “pegar” el driver de drupal para SQL Server, del siguiente modo:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Creamos nuestra base de datos en SQL Server.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Abrimos la carpeta del drupal con WebMatrix
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
4. En configuración, nos aseguramos que esté habilitado PHP
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
5. Nos conectamos a la base de datos desde WebMatrix
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
6. Clickeamos en el botón ejecutar y tenemos como resultado:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo anterior es basado en el tutorial que redacté hace unos años: https://fredyfx.wordpress.com/2013/03/18/drupal-en-iis-con-sql-server/

Hacemos uso de Microsoft WebMatrix para lograrlo. Espero te sea de utilidad, bendiciones.

Fredy