# ¿Como conectar mi sistema desarrollado en PHP con SQLSERVER en IIS?

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

Actualmente desarrollé un sistema en php, lo tenia en XAMPP y lo estaba usando con SQLSERVER 2014, descargué las librerías correspondientes y todo genial.
Pero ahora tengo que cambiar el sistema a un servidor con IIS, logré conectar el sistema con PHP usando CGI pero ahora no puedo conectarlo con SQLSERVER, no sé dónde poner las librerias srv para conectar con IIS así como lo había hecho con XAMPP.

*A continuación les muestro algunas imagenes:*

1. La primera es el error que muestra al no poder ejecutar la conexión con SQLserver

[image]

2. En esta segunda muestro las librerías que son para conectar el PHP con SQLserver, pero no se que hacer con ellas, no se donde las muevo .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Quizás esto te de ideas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2050/c%c3%b3mo-conectar-drupal-7-con-ms-sql-y-iis-7?rq=1

Comment: Fijate que yo lo he conectado con XAMPP y es como muestras en tu segundo comentario(mueves la librerias , editas ciertos archivos etc) pero con IIS no se que hacer con esas librerias para conectarlo con SQLserver.

Comment: Revisa esta guía: https://www.sitepoint.com/sql-server-php/